# Modified Longest Path Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, memoization

You are given a grid with `m` rows and `n` columns. Cell (0,0) contains the number 0 while all other cells contain some positive integer. By either moving down or to the right, we eventually make it to cell (`m`,`n`). The "length" of the path is the sum of the integers along the path.

The longest path problem sets out to find the maximum sum through the grid starting at (0,0) and ending at (`m`,`n`). This problem is sometimes solved using a combination of recursion and memoization.

If we modify the problem by adding an upper bound on the sum through the grid, can the dynamic programming approach using recursion and memoization be modified the solve the new problem?

For example, given a 4x4 grid:

```
0 2 3 4
2 4 3 1
3 4 3 2
4 3 2 1
```

and an upper bound of 4, the algorithm will determine there is no possible path from upper-left to lower-right satisfying that upper bound.

If instead we are given the upper bound of 15, we determine there is at least one path through the grid equal to or lower than 15, and return the greatest. In this case, we return 15.

If we are given an upper bound greater than the longest unconstrained path through the grid, then the problem simplifies to the longest path problem described above.